# regular expression matchinf for first occurrence

Tags: regex, perl, regex-greedy

I have a text's

```
case 1 :push ($arr, $var1);
case 2 : push $arr, $var1, $var2;
case 3 push ($arr, $var1, $var2);
```

I need to grep out capture it as
    `$1=push ( and $2 as $arr and $3 as , $var1, $var2);` for case 3

i tried it as

```
 /(.*push.*)(\$.*)(,.*)/
```

and `/(.*push.*)(\$.*)([^,]*)/` but it's not working for all the cases properly

Answer (score 0):

```
(push.*?)(\$\w+)(,.*)
```

it works